# Error installing twitter AnomalyDetection package from git

Tags: r

This is what I get when I attempt to install package AnomalyDetection.

```
Downloading GitHub repo twitter/AnomalyDetection@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/twitter/AnomalyDetection/zipball/master
Installing AnomalyDetection
```

> Error in `_digest`(c(list(repos, type), lapply(`_additional`,
>   function(x) eval(x[[2L]],  :    object 'digest_impl' not found

I am using Windows and R version 3.1.1.

Comment: Worked for me. Maybe try upgrading to R version 3.2.3 and retry?

Comment: This was the solution. After upgrading R the package installed succesfully. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884